# Exact Functors from Perverse Sheaves

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, micro-local-analysis

Pretty sure this is a simple question, but there's something I'm missing here.

For context, I'm reading 'An Elementary Construction of Perverse Sheaves' by MacPherson and Vilonen. A key aspect of the paper is the construction of a functor $\mathbf{P}(X) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$, where $\mathbf{P}(X)$ is the category of perverse sheaves on $X$ (constructible w.r.t. a fixed stratification) and $\mathcal{C}$ is some other category that isn't important now.

The authors have a simple argument to show that this functor is exact:

(i) They show that this functor is exact if and only if another functor, $\mathbf{Q}^{\bullet} \rightarrow H^{-d}(D^{\circ},K^{\circ};\mathbf{Q}^{\bullet})$ is exact. (Here $D^{\circ}$ and $K^{\circ}$ are certain subsets of $X$).

(ii) They show that $H^{k}(D^{\circ},K^{\circ};\mathbf{Q}^{\bullet}) = 0$ for $k > -d$ and $k < -d$, using the assumed properties of $D^{\circ}$, $K^{\circ}$, and the perversity of $\mathbf{Q}^{\bullet}$.

(iii) From this, they conclude the functor is exact.

I understand (i) and (ii), but I don't understand (iii). My best guess is that if you have a short exact sequence of perverse sheaves you can construct an exact triangle in the derived category, hence a LES of cohomology which becomes a SES using the vanishing result of (ii). I know a SES of complexes gives an LES in the derived category, but I don't know if there is an analogous result for perverse sheaves. My main confusion is in how to establish that a functor from the category of perverse sheaves is exact- I think the abelian structure on that category is a bit mysterious to me and if you give me a SES of perverse sheaves I'm not sure what to do with it.

Thanks

Comment: If $0 \to P' \to P \to P'' \to 0$ is a short exact sequence of perverse sheaves, then there is a map $P'' \to P'[1]$ in the derived category making $P' \to P \to P'' \to P'[1]$ into an exact triangle.  (I think this is the definition of "admissible" abelian subcategories of triangulated categories given by Beilinson-Bernstein-Deligne section 1.2; in section 1.3 they show the heart of a t-structure is admissible).